# How to send 2 TCP packets in c++

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

is it possible to send 2 consecutive TCP packets out as seen in this picture here: [image]

I currently have set TCP_NODELAY to true and SO_SNDBUF to 0. I have also called send in my program 2x. This is the result I obtained:

[image]

The main issue here will be the delayed-ack causing the slow network performance in the 2nd screenshot.

The code for the server:

```
DWORD WINAPI ServerHandler(void *lp){
    //The port you want the server to listen on
    int host_port = 1852;

    //Initialize socket support WINDOWS ONLY!
    unsigned short wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 2 );
    err = WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData );
    if ( err != 0 || ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 || HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 )) 
    {
        printf("Could not find useable sock dll %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    //Initialize sockets and set any options
    int hsock;
    BOOL bOptVal = true;
    int bOptLen = sizeof (BOOL);
    int iResult = 0;

    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(hsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error initializing socket %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    iResult = setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &bOptVal, bOptLen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("setsockopt for SO_REUSEADDR failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Set SO_REUSEADDR: ON\n");

    iResult = setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *) &bOptVal, bOptLen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("setsockopt for SO_KEEPALIVE failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Set SO_KEEPALIVE: ON\n");

    //Bind and listen
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ;

    if( bind( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        printf("Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(hsock);
        return 0;
    }
    if( listen( hsock, MAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        printf("Error listening %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(hsock);
        return 0;
    }

    //Now lets to the server stuff

    int* csock;
    sockaddr_in sadr;
    int addr_size = sizeof(SOCKADDR);
    
    printf("waiting for a connection\n");

    while(true)
    {            
        csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if((*csock = accept( hsock, (SOCKADDR*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            printf("Received connection from %s, %u @ socket %d\n", inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr), sadr.sin_port, *csock);
            
            BOOL bOptVal = true;            
            int iResult = setsockopt(*csock, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &bOptVal, sizeof(bOptVal));
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("setsockopt for TCP_NODELAY failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            else
                printf("Set TCP_NODELAY: TRUE\n");

            int sendBuf = 0;
            iResult = setsockopt(*csock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *) &sendBuf, sizeof(sendBuf));
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("setsockopt for SO_SNDBUF failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            else
                printf("Setsockopt for SO_SNDBUF set to 0\n");


            CreateThread(0,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock , 0,0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error accepting %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
    WSACleanup();
}
```

The code I used for sending data:

```
int send_TCP_2(int cs, char responseLength[], char data[], int respond_length, int data_length)
{   
    int size = respond_length + data_length;
    int index = 0;

    // combined 10 byte response with data as 1 packet
    std::vector<char> packet(size);

    for(int i=0; i<respond_length; i++)
    {
        packet[index] = responseLength[i];
        index++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<data_length; i++)
    {
        packet[index] = data[i];
        index++;
    }
    
    int status;
    char *data_ptr = &packet[0];
    while(size > 0)
    {
        status = send(cs, data_ptr, size, 0);
        if(status > 0)
        {
            data_ptr += status;
            size -= status;
        }
        else if (status == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
            printf("send_TCP_2 failed with error code: %d\n", error_code);
            return 0;   // send failed
        }
    }
    return 1;   // send successful  
}
```

[image]

I have attached the screenshot when I do not disable Nagle and not touching SO_SNDBUF.

Comment: What makes you think the size of the packets (and not something else) is affecting the network performance?  Are the two screenshots from the same pair of computers on the same network?

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` should be enough here.

Comment: @AdamLiss Oh no, I am not saying that the size of the packets is affecting the network. I am trying to get 2 packets out consecutively to get an immediate ACK. This will remove the 200ms delay seen in the 2nd picture. (0.011 to 0.210)

Comment: In what way do you imagine delayed ack causes slow network performance? The sending TCP stack should not be waiting to get the delayed ack before sending the next statement.

Comment: TCP is a sliding window protocol, not a stop-and-wait protocol.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I have already enabled TCP_NODELAY in the client socket.

Comment: Also, from the `man 7 socket` on Linux: `SO_SNDBUF
              Sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles this value (to
              allow  space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this dou‐
              bled  value  is  returned  by  getsockopt(2).   The  default  value  is   set   by   the
              /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default  file  and  the  maximum  allowed  value  is  set by the
              /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max file.  The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 2048.

Comment: I.e. setting `SO_SNDBUF` to 0 may not work everywhere. Is that documented on the OS you are using?

Comment: @Kaz I am not too sure about TCP but then why does the server sends almost immediately (time 0.221) the next packet right after the client sends its ACK (time 0.210)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8895/discussion-between-user990639-and-kaz)

Comment: As others have said, TCP_NODELAY should be what you're looking for to allow back to back transmissions.  If it's not working for you, you may be doing it wrong. Can we see some code?

Comment: @GuySirton I've attached the server code showing where I set the TCP_NODELAY and SO_SNDBUF.

Comment: Remove all of your settings changes. Then, test again. If you have a performance problem, post the trace so we can figure out what's wrong. But by pessimizing the stack, you are creating the problems you are seeing and ruining any hope of finding and fixing them. (Most likely, the problems you are having now are caused by small writes, Nagle being disabled, and small buffers. These are all problems you created.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand the problems that are created when I do small size sends and having Nagle disabled and even making the send buffer 0. However, I am interested in how another server can send out smaller size packets and at a faster timing compared to mine.

Because from what I see in the first picture, the server is able to send out individual packets of 206 bytes. I have tried disabling Nagle and what I saw was that some packets were still coalesce into bigger packet size.

Comment: @user990639: You won't be able to find out with all the settings changes you've done that make performance suck. Do everything *right* and then fix any performance problems you have. Everything you've done so far makes performance worse, so it's not surprising your performance is bad. Enable Nagle. Send as much data as possible in each call. Don't shrink the buffers. Then, if you have performance issues, we can help you find and fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the advise! Setting TCP_NODELAY to true will work as mentioned by most. I have made a silly mistake in setsockopt!

I should have put **IPPROTO_TCP** instead of **SOL_SOCKET**

Answer (score 3):

> The main issue here will be the delayed-ack causing the slow network
>   performance in the 2nd screenshot.

No it won't. You are mistaken about that. You don't have any control over TCP packetization, or rather segmentation, and you don't need it. TCP is a highly optimized stream transfer protocol developed over more than 30 years.

Comment: +1,000 You are trying to fix something that is not broken. At best, you won't break it. (However, more likely, you *will* break it by forcing small writes.)

Comment: TCP ain't perfect.  TCP is the hammer we have, so we keep nailing screws into the wall.  For request/response communication, TCP has notable shortcomings, especially with regard to windowing.  There's plenty of discussion on the web about the downsides of the TCP windowing scheme in conjunction with the tendency of modern HTTP to open a boatload of TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

`TCP_NODELAY option set to TRUE` should fix the delayed_ACK problem. I once had to send the network packet twice but i did it in the `ETHERNET (driver) layer` and it worked there (the delayed_ACK was caused by the other party), but in this layer (SOCKET layer) you can not do such a thing. Also, do not set SO_SNDBUF to 0...